# Forward and Backward Fast Fourier Transform, shuift by half period

Tags: fftw

I have a simple problem that i'm not managing to solve.
I am simply taking the dft of a periodical sequence of numbers (using the fftw3 in fortran), and I noticed that, when taking the inverse transform, the output is the initial sequence, but shifted by exactly one half of the period. Can someone tell me what is the problem? I think I am missing something in the functioning of the fftw3

Comment: You mean you use `FFTW_FORWARD` and `FFTW_BACKWARD`? Those just define the sign in the exponential. As usual in FFT, the zero component is DC, so the output is rearranged. This might cause your observation.

Comment: I think we need to see a [mcve].